# Error while getting Contacts from Microsoft graph api

Tags: swift, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch a user's Contacts using the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ios-swift-connect-sample). I am able to get the user details using `graphClient.me()`, but when I try to get a list of contacts I am getting an error:

```
Graph SDK ERROR : 
  Error from data task : 
    Error Domain=com.microsoft.graph.errors 
    Code=400 "bad request" 
    UserInfo={
      NSLocalizedDescription=bad request, 
      error= AuthenticationError : Error authenticating with resource
    }

Graph SDK ERROR : Caused by request <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1738bc70> { 
  URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts 
}
```

My Code:

```c
self.graphClient.me().contacts().request().getWithCompletion {
  (_ contacts: MSCollection?,
   _ nextRequest: MSGraphUserContactsCollectionRequest?,
   _ error: Error?) in

    if error == nil {
        print("contacts \(contacts)")
    }
    else {
        print("error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

My Scopes:

```c
let SCOPES   = ["openid", "profile","User.Read","Contacts.Read"]
```

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the contacts using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: No, the Same error I am getting, But when I log in with the different account I am able to get results. But with that particular account, I am not able to get results. Don't know what wrong with that account. Had given all required permissions.

Comment: Are you sure they have an Exchange Online mailbox? You can confirm by attempting to open the user's mailbox using [Outlook for the Web](https://outlook.office.com/owa/).

Comment: No, I am not able to log in, it says 'Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.We received a bad request.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/contacts` endpoint requires that the `user` has an accessible Exchange Mailbox. If the user doesn't have a mailbox provisioned in Exchange Online for this tenant, several endpoints that rely on Exchange will fail (`/contacts`, `/events`, `/messages`, etc.).